# Disable auto focus on drop-down open of select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I tried to disable auto focus of input search inside `select2` especially on mobile to disable keyboard popup. However, as documented [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1908#issuecomment-76546178):

> **select2** will not be triggering the native events. select2 will also
>   not be triggering non-native versions of the events, which is less of
>   an issue as we still have the option to add the native events without
>   breaking compatibility.

So the only way I could do is to try to get every input box inside select2 that was currently on focused and set lose focus, but has no luck.

```
$("select").select2().on("select2-open",":input",function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(":focus").blur();
    }, 50);
});
```

Is there any possibility that I could achieve that result above? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995057/prevent-select2-from-autmatically-focussing-its-search-input-when-dropdown-is-op.

Comment: @andreivictor, the answers there does not solve my problem, target version is v4 while I'm using select2 v3,  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I managed to find solution which works just fine for me as below:

```
/* Hide keyboard on select2 open event */
function hideSelect2Keyboard(e){
    $('.select2-search input, :focus,input').prop('focus',false).blur();
}

$("select").select2().on("select2-open", hideSelect2Keyboard);

$("select").select2().on("select2-close",function(){
    setTimeout(hideSelect2Keyboard, 50);
});
```

Tested on Tablet, and iOS device. In function `hideSelect2Keyboard()`, I searched for every current focus element, include input field which could be used to initialized select2, setting `.prop('focus',false)` which will remove focus and consequently disable keyboard popup on `select2-open` and `select2-close` event, by chaining `.blur()` is to remove focus border from element. Then I attached this function to select event `open` and `close` and it works just fine.

I hope this will help other who searching for this as me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a solution for `select v3` - tested in `v3.5.4`.

We can use the option `shouldFocusInput`, which must be a function that should return `true` or `false`.

So initialize the plugin with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2({
    shouldFocusInput: function() {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Codepen demo: https://codepen.io/andreivictor/pen/JmNzvb

If you want to disable the auto-focus only on mobile devices, my approach is to use Modernizr library, which can test for the existence of Touch Events in the browser.

So the complete code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2({
    shouldFocusInput: function() {
      if (Modernizr.touch) {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I've tested your answer but it still does not work, I don't know why `shouldFocusInput:-1` does not work as it documented. Finally, I found solution as in my answer. +1 with thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I've tested my answer on Android devices, it works fine. On iOS, the input does not get focused when dropdown opens. However, after being focused manually, it remains focused even after the dropdown closes.

Comment: perhaps need to doing sth on close event too.

Comment: my problem right now is my select2 on iphone does not work well, it does not open on single click but double or triple click, I have no idea why it does not show anything in console. I want to open another new question on SO but I could not reproduce problem sample code to post sadly..

Comment: your select2 is not working due to the hack that you made in order to disable auto-focus (`hideSelect2Keyboard`)?

Comment: I don't think so, it does not work well on iphone since before I had made anything to it.

Comment: this is strange... however, is updating select2 to v4 an option for you? v3 is quite old at this moment..

Comment: I've been acknowledged about this fixed bug in v4, yet I'm unable to migrate it since my template solely using v3  for its main js file. pixelsAdmin https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/pixeladmin-responsive-template-WB07403R9 currently used v4 but mine is old version haha :D

Answer (score 0):

this is in the top google results for *"select2 disable focus when cleared"*

here is the solution for Select2 4.0.0 | Select2 4.1.1

```
$("select").on("select2:clear", function (evt) {
  $(this).on("select2:opening.cancelOpen", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    
    $(this).off("select2:opening.cancelOpen");
  });
});
```

**Source Thread:**
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3320#issuecomment-524153140

jump to [kevin-brown - Aug 22, 2019]

seo tldr;

- clear button in select2 4.x causes focus
- stop select2 from regaining focus after clear
- select2 disable focus when cleared

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why, but the above solutions didn't work for me. But this one worked-

```
$('select').on('select2:open', function (event) {
    $('.select2-search input').prop('focus',false);
});
```